# AEM Eclipse Plugin Issues

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adobe, aem

I am facing issues while trying to create a new AEM project using the Eclipse plugin provided.
  I did an offline install of the plugin and the archetypes since the proxy was blocking the install site.
  I am not able to proceed in the create dialog, it throws 'Unhandled event loop exception' exception in eclipse with the below stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process archetype: null
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at
>
> com.adobe.granite.ide.eclipse.ui.wizards.np.AdvancedSettingsComponent.initialize(AdvancedSettingsComponent.java:253)

I tried using Kepler, Luna as well as Mars versions of eclipse.

Hope someone has an answer to this error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a complete stack trace? Also, it would be good to retry with the latest version of the plugin

Comment: Did you solve the issue? That happens to me when I'm trying to create a new project.

Comment: @JuancarlosRodríguez Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring the project to be either a bundle project or a content project? You can do this by selecting the project, right click, select Configure option and then the right option.